# What machine learning algorithm is appropriate for shooting basketballs?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, robotics

We are making a robot that shoots basketballs into hoops.

From an image and our knowledge of the camera's angle and the target's dimensions (the targets are coated with retroreflective tape), we know how far away we are, X and Y (distance being Z, more or less)

This is fed into the machine learning algorithm, which should spit out

1. Speed to be sent to the canon
2. Horizontal tilt
3. Vertical tilt

What kind of machine learning algorithm is this, and how would you train it?

Comment: If you know your current position, target position, why do you need machine learning at all? You can just calculate speed and tilt

Comment: @Archeg: We only know our current position relative to the target. The point of the machine learning algorithm is to figure out how input relates to output (e.g, what the drag for the ball is, etc)

Comment: Machine learning is usefull when you do not know what enviroment variables will influence your result. Or if it is difficult to hardcode them. In your case I still can't see them. Do you need to check strength of wind, is it possible to have some obstacles around or maybe you should use different balls with different mass and surface? Machine learning is a great tool, but it's slow and never smart enough. So it's good to think, why do you need it at all.

Comment: I need to learn, then apply my learning to shoot accuratly. What I need to learn is roughly how much tilt hear affects landing position there, how force affects distance, etc. (However, the team suggests using bowling balls to destory competeing robots, so we may need to learn how to shoot those, too. :))

Answer (score 4):

Machine Learning is probably not appropriate for this task. At least, not by itself. Use physics. You should be able to get a rough formula for this out of a first-semester physics textbook, though you'll need to decide whether you're aiming for the middle of the hoop or the board behind it.

Your physics formulae should tell you the angle and force to use, but your model of the system will have some inaccuracies. Different balls may have different mass, and you might not want to explicitly account for air resistance, and so on. A search through the space of offsets based on how close the previous shot was could work. The choice of search methods is up to you - simulated annealing could work well, as Mencel said.

One possible use for machine learning here might be to remember and extrapolate these offsets. A function approximator (such as a neural network) could be used to learn the offsets from experience. Once your search method succeeds at putting the ball in the hoop, use this as a training example for an approximator that learns to map from what the physics model says to use to the offsets that made the shot work. Then, for the next shot (from whatever position), the function approximator would be used to guess the offsets to use. If that shot misses, repeat the search until correct offsets are found. Update the function approximator, rinse, and repeat. Also, it would probably be beneficial if your function approximator were initialized in such a way that it initially always says to apply no offsets - after all, the best first guess should be to just use what the physics model tells you to use.

Comment: The most physics is going to give us is a very rough approximate - unless you know the the drag of a small foam basketball with burn marks on it?

How exactly would a neural network work?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a reinforcement learning approach. It'll be slow ; so maybe you could initialize the solution with your own estimate (basic physics) and refine it with reinforcement learning.

Comment: What exactly do you suggest? Can you be more specific? (I'm sorry, I have a very basic grasp of machine learning)